# after migrate opencart to another hosting some images lost

Tags: php, opencart, web-hosting

i have a porblem with opencart 3 when i migrated my theme and database to another hosting products images lost.
some folders have a turkish characters like ( **Ö,Ü,Ğ,Ç,I, and space like First Product** ) and with this situation website can't read this folders and shows error 404 for products's images, i have a 400 products inside my shop and i cant change it one by one its take more time, can you help me to resolve that from capnel or phpmyadmin.

---

My hositing company: Hostinger 
PHP Version: PHP 7.4.x
https://innturk.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=207

---

Comment: "website can't read this folders" - what does that mean? Sounds like an encoding issue in the file system. Are you sure the webserver itself is configured properly?

Comment: yes i configured it and every thing is ok except this folders, and encode system at utf-8 and this folders was working with old server that i used to.